# Can I extend a tub/shower diverter nipple?

Tags: plumbing, bathtub

I need a longer non-standard tub/shower diverter in a finished tub surround.  The threaded nipple I have now is short (works, but spills onto the overflow).

Question: How can I extend that nipple? I can buy a Slip-On Tub Spout if needed.

Can I use PEX because I don't trust my pipe sweating abilities?

Similar to what I have

[image: Similar]

EDIT:

The existing pipe is already soldered into the value and passes through a recently finished wall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, you should be able to remove that nipple and get one that fits your extended spout. Many stores will custom make one.

Depending on the additional length you need, you can add a coupling and a small nipple to the end of what you've got already.

Also, cut the existing nipple and install a sharkbite coupling or compression connector (depending on material, assuming copper since it's sweated, to give you a small additional amount.

Comment: That nipple is installed to the value beneath the wall.  I'm trying to avoid a plumber opening the back wall and sweating in a new pipe.